# Which user data are apps able to collect by default?

Tags: applications, permissions, privacy

On Android, I used to prefer the mobile website of services instead of their app because of possible privacy concerns. Now I'm wondering if this is actually unnecessary.

So my question is: **Which device or user data are apps able to collect without granting any explicit permissions by the user?**

Can they read my phone number, IMEI, can they see other installed apps etc.?

Let's assume it's a freshly installed app that I've never opened so far.

Comment: Though this might not be an answer to your question, take a look at Google's permission documentation (aimed at developers): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous

Any permission in the "normal" category is given when the app is installed. Any permission listed as "dangerous" requires explicit permission through a pop-up to access.

Comment: If you give permission to an app when installing and it requires you to permit them to read your Gallery. You have given them access. Now whether to access your photo to show/display in app, or upload it to their server for illegal purpose, it completely upon developer's intentions. That's why you need to think twice before installing any app. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @gertmenkel There are two exceptions to the rule: if your Android is Lollipop or lower, all requested permissions will be automatically granted; if you run Marshmallow or newer and an app targets Lollipop or lower, all requested permissions will be granted, while the dangerous ones will be able to be manually revoked.